# SQL Server use a text file for in the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I have what seems like should be a simple question but can't find a simple answer.  I have only "read" privilege, not "write".

I want to create a simple query such as:
           Select a, b, c
           from x
           where a in (c:\myfilename.txt)

Is this possible considering my limitations (read only)?

Comment: Is this a one time thing or a job you will want to run often?  How big is the file you are looking at?  Do you have SSIS?  (there are many ways to do this all depending on these questions)

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2016.  It is an ongoing thing since the question has come up before but for not just a one off.  I don't want to insert a huge list into the sql query but rather get it directly from its file location.  The file I am referring to is +4000 rows.

Comment: For now just a one off.

Comment: A lot of times people who dont have access to the DB have access to TEMP, have you seen if you have access to create a table in the TEMP db?  If so you can import your file into there and select from that table in TEMP.  If it is only 4000, you can use Excel to build out a way to import the data in a subselect inside your query itself (I can show that if interested), it is not ideal, but works.

Comment: I have not tried, but maybe you can use OPENROWSET in a CTE?

Comment: I was able to do this:

Comment: Create Table ##temp1 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int);
 successfully...does that mean I have access to the TempDB ?

Comment: @ORLANDOVAZQUEZ Yes, but I would recommend not using ## for temp tables as they create global temp tables insted of scoped.  Use #temp1 instead of ##temp1.

Comment: Yes that would give you access to the temp DB, then you can import the data into that temp table and use that table in your query

Comment: To expand a bit on what squillman said, the global temp table is visible by all processes and stays in the DB until you remove it (or SQL is restarted).  If yo uuse the #TempTableName instead the temp table only stays active in your current session and is automatically removed when the session ends (and is not visible outside your session)

Comment: @ORLANDOVAZQUEZ Do you know if you have BULK permissions?  Try creating a text file with a, b, c on different lines then run this: `CREATE TABLE #t (ID VARCHAR(255));
BULK INSERT #t
FROM 'D:\SO.txt';`  Change D:\SO.txt to be the path to your text file.

Comment: No bulk permissions.  I will drop any temp table I create .

Comment: Brad, I saved the data in a column in Excel.

Comment: Again not the most ideal solution but it works.  past this in Excel and replace the A1 with whatever column you are looking at for your data.  ="Select '" &A1&"' AS FieldName UNION ALL"  Then copy this forumula all the way down for every row in your file and then copy the results of the formula into your SQL script (remove last UNION ALL in the code) and you can use that in your in statement, or you can use that to create a temp table and/or table variable.

Comment: Bummer.  That rules out `OPENROWSET` as well...  Afraid you're left with SSIS, Import Data Wizard, or writing a script outside of SQL Server to create a temp table (Powershell, or some other language).  You can create formulas in Excel to generate your inserts.  But all of that is still pretty manual, except for something in SSIS.

Comment: I posted my Excel option in greater detail as an answer below

Comment: Brad, is there a way to modify this so that it imports data from the file ?  INSERT INTO dbo.#temp1  (CML)
VALUES (1)

Comment: I got it to work as per suggestions given using:

insert into dbo.#temp1  (CML) values(11016031)  
insert into dbo.#temp1  (CML) values(11016684)  
insert into dbo.#temp1  (CML) values(11016750)  
insert into dbo.#temp1  (CML) values(11017164)  
insert into dbo.#temp1  (CML) values(11017317)  
insert into dbo.#temp1  (CML) values(11017318)  
insert into dbo.#temp1  (CML) values(11017388)

Answer (score 2):

A bit better format for the Excel option I posted in Comments (again this is not ideal or best but it works).  It is down and dirty but works when permissions lacking or just for a quick one off.

In Excel copy this into a cell on the same row of your data (and replace the A1 with the column of your data):

```
="Select '" &A1&"' AS FieldName UNION ALL"
```

NOTE:  If you have multiple columns you can do it that way as well just edit the formula similar to this for multiple columns:

```
="Select '" &A1&"' AS FieldName, '"&B1&"' as FieldName2 UNION ALL"
```

Then copy this formula all the way down for every row in your file.

Then copy the results of your formula, should look something like this:

```
Select '1' AS FieldName UNION ALL
Select '2' AS FieldName UNION ALL
Select '3' AS FieldName UNION ALL
```

(to make the text smaller when copying from Excel to SQL the "AS FieldName " could just be "AS F " or you can just leave that off completely (if dealing with one field).  If dealing with a LOT of rows that could speed up copy/paste a bit and make your file smaller for your SQL script.  Those few characters add up after a while.

Then remove the last UNION ALL (or it wont be valid SQL).

Then you can use it like this in your code:

```
Select a, b, c 
from x 
where a in (
    Select '1' AS FieldName UNION ALL
    Select '2' AS FieldName UNION ALL
    Select '3' AS FieldName 
)
```

If you have a LOT of data you can do something like this instead to make it a bit easier to read (but still have a ton at the top of your script).

```
-- OR USE temp table instead of table variable
DECLARE @TableData AS TABLE (
    FieldValue VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TableData 
Select '1' AS FieldName UNION ALL
Select '2' AS FieldName UNION ALL
Select '3' AS FieldName 


Select a, b, c 
from x 
where a in (
    SELECT FieldValue
    FROM @TableData
)
```

Comment: I do this very similar with "insert into @t values('" & a1 & "')" And paste that all the way down

Comment: also I use join instead of in(select...)

Comment: I do this All. The. Time for one-offs.